# C++/CLI cli::array<double,2>, how to access from CS .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I'll preface this with the fact I don't know either language besides tinkering with others' code.  But I'm modifying code to vectorize it and have the C++/CLI portion figured out as this structure:
`cli::array<double,2>^% vols`
Initialized like this:
`vols = gcnew cli::array<double, 2>(2,dealIDs->Length);`
So that all compiles fine and I have a 2D array with 2x (Length of dealsID) on the C++ side.  Now on the NET side I'm not sure the correct declaration. What is this the correct .NET CS format to access my 2xN structured C++/CLI array?  Much appreciated.

Comment: It is just a plain `double[,]` on the C# side.  How the IntelliSense popup did not help you fall into that pit of success is very hard to guess when you post this little repro code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gcnew cli::array<double, 2>(2,dealIDs->Length);
```

would be in C# syntax

```
new double[2, deals.Length]
```

A `List<T>` is not an array.

Comment: Thank you @adjan that is what I'm searching for.  Is the proper declaration then in .NET `public double[][] variable` or `public double[,] variable` as @Hans Passant stated?

Comment: `public double[,] identifier`

Comment: I just want to note for those working with a `List` on the NET side the format instead of `.Length` is `.Count`, i.e. `myvariable = new double[2, dealIDs.Count]`